# Required parameter State in Billing/Shipping Address - 3D Secure 2 - SCA

Tags: global-payments-api

We are using global payments Hosted Payment Page for accepting payments from our members. We are planning to enable 3D Secure 2 to be compliant with new SCA requirements. After going through the documentation for required parameters in the request, I see that State parameter on Billing and Shipping address is required where one is available in ISO 3166-2.

Is there a reliable database where I can get ISO 3166-2 subdivision codes and is this required for all the countries where there are official subdivision codes?

Also, We invoice companies and not individuals, therefore the Billing address is not necessarily the address of the cardholder. Is this an issue?

Any help much appreciated.